# Dissecting XML over TCP packets in wireshark

Tags: xml, tcp, wireshark

Does XML dissector of wireshark take care of reassembling PDUs if protocol uses XML over TCP

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean raw XML over TCP - not, for example, XML inside of an HTTP body or a SIP body or something else on top of TCP?  For raw XML over TCP, no I don't think it handles TCP reassembly, though I could be wrong.  For XML inside another protocol, like in a MIME body inside another protocol, then yes it does so long as the protocol it's inside of handles it (which most do, as far as I know).  That's because XML doesn't even know about it in those cases; the lower-level protocol handles the reassembly.  It's usually up to the protocol directly on top of TCP to handle figuring out what makes up a full one of their "messages", and XML is just a blob inside their whole message.